# How do I display a list of upcoming events in Gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a collection of markdown files for events with a frontmatter field 'date' set to the date of the event.

I can't figure out how I would use graphql to query for events with dates in the future, limit 3. And if it can't be done with graphql, how could it be done?

```
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: {order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date]},
        filter: {frontmatter: {layout: {eq: "Event"}}},
        limit: 3) 
        {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              fields {
                slug
              }
              frontmatter {
                title
                layout
                date
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter once all your posts have been queried by GraphQL:

```
const Posts = edges
    .filter( edgeItem => edgeItem.node.frontmatter.date > Date.now())
    .map(({ node }) => <PostItem key={node.id} node={node} /> )
```

If your date is stored as a string, convert it first to make the comparison. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date